# Why can't I pass a variable to a chart method in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

This is my code to hide a chart series based on user inputs of "yes" or "no" into a range of cells.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal rng As Range)
Set rng = Range("I23:I31")

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 9
    If rng.Cells(i, 1).Value = "no" Then
        Worksheets("DASHBOARD1").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(i).IsFiltered = True
    Else
        Worksheets("DASHBOARD1").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(i).IsFiltered = False
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

However, I'm getting an error because of the `i` in the `FullSeriesCollection(i)` method. This runs fine if I replace the `i` with a numeric value. Is there anyway I can pass the `i` variable into the method? Otherwise I can just be more explicit in the code and use numeric values.

Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting ("index out of bounds"?), and have you tried hard-coding all possible values of `i` (1 through 9)? Does the chart have 9 series?

Comment: Thanks so much, just as you said the issue was that the chart only had 8 series even though I coded for 9 iterations!